# Getting Promise { <pending> } with NodeJS and express

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hello i'm getting Promise {  } when i try to log my products. Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong and fix this ? I can't figure it out. Thanks!

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.port || 3000;
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

let products = getData();

async function getData() {
await fetch('some link',
    {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }
).then(res => res.json())
.then((res) => {return res.json})
};

console.log(products);
```

Comment: `getData` isn't returning anything, so I don't see how you'd even get that Promise logged.

Comment: Here's example code hopefully explaining the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/oLucg1bx/ (bottom line: you can *never* escape the fact that fetch is async, you cannot magically convert async code into sync code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `products` variable is a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) for the data you're fetching.

To get the result you have to wait for its fulfillment for example like so:

`products.then(console.log);`

Also, as was pointed out, the syntax of your `getData` function is not quite right. Here is a "fixed" version:

```
function getData() {
    return fetch('some link', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => res.json);
}
```

Comment: This fixed it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you confused the usage of promise and `async`-`await`.

When `async` is used on certain function, you need to use the `await` keyword on a statement that return a promise object. for example:

```
async function getData() {
    const res = await fetch('some link', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    })
    const resJSON = await res.json()
    console.log(res.json)
};
```

if you decide to use promise instead of `async`-`await`, then remove it completelly from the code

```
function getData() {
    fetch('some link', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res) => res.json)
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Async function will always return a promise.
You can define the products outside then assign the value to products after you get the response.

```js
let products = null;

getData().then(res => {
    products = res
    console.log(products)
})

async function getData() {
    let result = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    return result.json()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the call to `fetch` inside `getData` and then await the call to `getData`.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.port || 3000;
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

async function getData() {
  return fetch('some link',
    {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }
  ).then(res => res.json())
  .then((res) => {return res.json})
};

(async () => {
  let products = await getData();
  console.log(products);
})()
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `.then((res) => {return res.json})` is nonsense. (unless the server's reply actually returns an object that has a `json` field)

Comment: @ChrisG I assume that is the case, yes.

Comment: Now i'm getting undefined at the end ? Any ideas ?

Comment: What URL are you calling?

Comment: In the second then(), you should change `return res.json` to `return res`